# which operation should be used to store unsigned result from mul in register other than rax

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

```
mov rax, 2
mov rbx, 2
mul rbx, rax //This does not exist
```

How would I have to write the above example without using any additional `mov` instructions?

Im using `x86-64` assembly.

Comment: Do you want the high-half result anywhere (what `mul` puts in RDX)?  If so,  you need one-operand `mul` (or BMI2 `mulx`).  If not, use `imul rdi, rsi` or whatever, like a compiler would.

Comment: If you want a 64-bit result, use `imul rbx, rax`. If you want a 128-bit result, you have to use `mul rbx`, which puts the result in rdx:rax.